# Service undefined when mocking inside Pipe unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to mock a service inside a unit test for a Pipe. The problem I'm facing is that even after following multiple guides and using many methods I still get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformDateToApi' of undefined` error when executing the test.

I've seen others perform this task on components, but for a Pipe it's slightly different, right?

*date.pipe.spec.ts*

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DatePipe } from './date.pipe';
import { DateFormat } from '@app/enums';
import { ApiService } from '@app/services';
import { MainService } from '@app/state';

class MockApiService extends ApiService {
    transformDateToApi(date: Date = new Date()): string {
        return '13-08-1996T22:10:32';
    }
}

describe('DatePipe', () => {
    const testDate = new Date('13-08-1996T22:10:32');
    const testDateAsString = '13-08-1996 22:10:32';

    const pipe = new DatePipe();
    let apiService: ApiService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                { provide: ApiService, useClass: MockApiService },
                { provide: MainService, useValue: {} }
            ]
        });
        apiService = TestBed.get(ApiService);
    });

    // Date object test
    it('date (as Date object) will be properly transformed in DateFormat.Xshort format', () => {
        expect(pipe.transform(testDate, DateFormat.Xshort)).toBe('13-08-\'96');
    });
    it('date (as Date object) will be properly transformed in DateFormat.Short format', () => {
        expect(pipe.transform(testDate, DateFormat.Short)).toBe('13-08-1996');
    });
    it('date (as Date object) will be properly transformed in DateFormat.Pretty format', () => {
        expect(pipe.transform(testDate, DateFormat.Pretty)).toBe('13 augustus 1996');
    });
    it('date (as Date object) will be properly transformed in DateFormat.WithTime format', () => {
        expect(pipe.transform(testDate, DateFormat.WithTime)).toBe('13 augustus 1996 22:10:32');
    });
});
```

*date.pipe.ts*

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '@app/services';
import { DateFormat } from '@app/enums';
import { DateSegments } from '@app/interfaces';

@Pipe({
    name: 'formatDate'
})
export class DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    private date: DateSegments;

    constructor (
        private apiService: ApiService
    ) { }

    transform(date: Date | string, format: DateFormat = DateFormat.Pretty): string {
        if ( date instanceof Date ) {
            console.log(this.apiService);
            console.log(ApiService);
            date = this.apiService.transformDateToApi(date);
        }

..... (irrelevant code to this question)
```

The Error I'm receiving is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformDateToApi' of undefined`.

At this point my trial and error strategy has been brought back to just smashing code together, a strategy that doesn't teach me anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

Pipes are very simple, you should not use the test bed to test them. Instead, mock your service and simply create the pipe with it by injecting it. Something like this.

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DatePipe } from './date.pipe';
import { DateFormat } from '@app/enums';
import { ApiService } from '@app/services';
import { MainService } from '@app/state';

const apiServiceMock = {
  transformDateToApi(date: Date = new Date()): string {
    return '13-08-1996T22:10:32';
  }
};

describe('DatePipe', () => {
  const testDate = new Date('13-08-1996T22:10:32');
  const testDateAsString = '13-08-1996 22:10:32';

  let pipe: DatePipe;
  let apiService: ApiService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: ApiService, useValue: apiServiceMock },
        { provide: MainService, useValue: {} }
      ]
    });
    apiService = TestBed.get(ApiService);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    pipe = new DatePipe(apiServiceMock as any);
  });

  // Date object test
  it('date (as Date object) will be properly transformed in DateFormat.Xshort format', () => {
    expect(pipe.transform(testDate, DateFormat.Xshort)).toBe('13-08-\'96');
  });
  it('date (as Date object) will be properly transformed in DateFormat.Short format', () => {
    expect(pipe.transform(testDate, DateFormat.Short)).toBe('13-08-1996');
  });
  it('date (as Date object) will be properly transformed in DateFormat.Pretty format', () => {
    expect(pipe.transform(testDate, DateFormat.Pretty)).toBe('13 augustus 1996');
  });
  it('date (as Date object) will be properly transformed in DateFormat.WithTime format', () => {
    expect(pipe.transform(testDate, DateFormat.WithTime)).toBe('13 augustus 1996 22:10:32');
  });
});
```

Comment: *you should not use the test bed to test them* - that's not true. TestBed isn't needed to test their main functionality (this provides isolated unit tests), but @Pipe annotation and DI annotation remain untested. It may fail in production or e2e with obscure error even with unit tests being green.

Comment: That was my point, to test them in e2e testing. I was proposing a solution for the unit testing, which is supposed to test if the business rules are applied.

Comment: And apparently, to avoid any issue, you should **[write DOM tests](https://angular.io/guide/testing#pipe-testing)** too. Didn't know that, so thank you for making me look at the documentation !

Comment: TestBed serves as common denominator here, I'd go DOM test only, unless a pipe is complex and has methods besides `transform`. Pipe class can also be registered as a provider in TestBed in order to test DI.

Comment: ever heard of isolation in a unit test? you totally break this if you are testing the service by using a pipe

Comment: He tries to test a pipe with his à service, not the opposite